# how to send a checkbox using ajax without clicking any submit button when div unloads

Tags: javascript, ajax, checkbox, fancybox, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to set a done button on my fancybox, when the user checks the checkbox it will be mark as done, the checkbox value will be submitted after the div on the fancybox has unload, and there is no submit button to click,  the value will only be sent when the div inside the fancybox has unload, i'm using ajax to submit the value,

"the problem is when the fancybox unloads the "function donerem()" does not execute even when i'm using onbeforeunload"

[image: fancybox]

ajaxscript: this is supposed to fire after the fancybox close

```
var R = jQuery.noConflict();
//REMINDER done Submit ===============================================================================
function donerem(){
    if ($('input[name=done]').attr('checked') === 'checked') {
    alert ('checked');
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    var dataString = 'msg_id=' + ID;
    R.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "database/clientpanel/wall/donerem.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
                alert ('done');
                var div = document.getElementById("rem" + ID);
                div.parentNode.removeChild(div);

        }
    });


    }
    else
    alert ('not checked');
return false;
});
}
```

fancybox : the done button

```
<div align="left" class="post_box" onbeforeunload="donerem()">
<input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="done">
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear as to which bit you're specifically struggling with. Can you clarify what the main issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if I've understood the question.
To check whether it's selected or not you can use the following:

```
if ($('input[name=done]').attr('checked') === 'checked') {
    // selected
}
else {
    // not selected
}
```

You could make it shorter like so:

```
var selected = ($('input[name=done]').attr('checked') === 'checked') ? true : false;
```

When fancybox closes you need to fire off your AJAX call.
You can do this by assigning a listener to the event like so:

```
$("#some-element").fancybox({
    'scrolling' : 'no',
    'titleShow' : false,
    'onClosed' : function() {
        // make AJAX request
        donerem();
    }
});
```

Found this code from the fancybox blog: http://fancybox.net/blog

Comment: i'm trying to send a value to aajax without the aid of a submit button